# How to get a HtmlElement by Id

Tags: coded-ui-tests

Need to find a HtmlElement by Id (coded-ui). I got a BrowserWindow. Can find a specific element (table, cell, button, etc.), but not just an arbitrary element by its Id. E.g., the following h3 (in real life the h3 is part of complex table cell. We don't need the cell, we just need the header).

```
<html>
<body>
   <h3 id='check'>Check this text!</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody an idea how to do this? Thanks in advace!
Gerard

Answer (score 0):

After you've recorded the steps you desire on your `[TestMethod]`,
 you should have sub-methods in the form

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyTestMethod()
{
    this.UIMap.XXXX();
    this.UIMap.YYYY();
    this.UIMap.ZZZZ();
}
```

Click on a sub-method with your mouse and press F12, that should open the `UIMap.Designer.cs` in which you can see the recorded steps..

Now just right click on the control you want and expand the `Search Criteria`.

Depending on the type of element it would look something like this :

`this.mUITboxXXXX.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id] = "Replace here with what you want"`

Edit : Example of a crosshair on text inside an h3 tag:[image]

Comment: It is not always a control. Sometimes a header <h3>some text that need to checked</h3>, somtimes a <p>, whatever. Does that work too?

Comment: yeah.. they are still HTML elements... You'd just need to search for the appropriate one in the file and match it on the search criteria. Or you could go to your `UIMap.uitest` file and on the right side find the control you want and check it's properties.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Sorry, guess I miss the point. Yes it is HTML, but not a control. Make the most simple HTML: <html>...<h3 id='check'>Check this text</h3>...</html> Now drag the crosshair on 'Check this text'. It fails. Yes, in real life this h3 is part of a complex table cell, so we don't want the cell, but just a part of it. Any idea?

Comment: Think of the cell as a container of the text.. so inside of it you have it's properties, among them you have `Inner Text` per instance. Give me a sec and I'll try something here on a browser for you.

Comment: You can use the crosshair directly on the text and you will to whom it belongs, then you can check your UIMap for hierarchy and etc.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We got that result too. Problem is that the innerText is (in real life) not just the H3 content, but a lot of other things. In your example you hit the BODY (without an Id) and not the H3 with an Id. Parsing the content (innerText) is quite a job.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96679/discussion-between-onilol-and-gerard).

Answer (score 0):

Onilol suggested the following (which works fine as the id is fixed and we just need the text):

```
var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("http://www.oursite.check/");
object txt = browser.ExecuteScript("return $('#check').text()", null);
```