# Coded UI- Can't find Specific Control to Test

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, coded-ui-tests

I am building an automation for web app in coded-UI , and i can not recognize a specific control that appears inside an i-Frame.
the specific control is "form" and the i-Fram shows me an outsource ASP.NET website.

can someone help to know if i am missing a dll reference or doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things that can't be recorded. Some of them can however be programmed. The list of Html tags that is recognized is restricted. See [How to get a HtmlElement by Id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996333/how-to-get-a-htmlelement-by-id) for a workaround.